# How can I ensure my process never locks another process out of a file?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, file-locking

I have a Windows process that runs in the background and periodically backs up files. The backup is done by uploading the file to a server.

During the backup, I don't want to lock any other application out of writing to or reading from the file; if another applications wants to change the file, I should stop the upload and close the file.

Share mode is useless here; even though I'm sharing all access to the file being read, if the other process attempts to open it for writing without sharing read, it will be locked out of the file.

Is it possible to accomplish this on Windows, without writing a driver?

Comment: This doesn't seem possible, even with writing a driver. You'd have to make sure no processes started with intent to lock the file while you were working with it, which either requires predicting to the future or not locking the file while you read it (which may cause partial uploads or other bad stuff).

Comment: The software handles this by noticing that the file was changed during upload, then stopping and alerting the server that the file should be dropped. It's ported from OS X, where this is possible. Not locking the file while reading is what I want.

Comment: Welcome to the hell that is Windows non-advisory file locking... I hope you find a solution to this, because I haven't yet found a clean way around this problem.

Comment: You may want to look at the [VSS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384645(v=vs.85).aspx). Can't tell exactly tell how to implement it, but I've seen few posts about people using it for backing up SQL files and what not.

Comment: I'm trying everything possible to avoid even looking at VSS. I also have the problem that the files in question are very large; they're often double digit gigabytes.

Comment: @dauphic: VSS may be complex, but the file size shouldn't be a concern. In normal operation, VSS doesn't duplicate the entire file when a snapshot is taken - the shadow copy tracks differences on the bock level using a copy-on-write mechanism. In other words, the only additional storage required for the VSS snapshot is to hold blocks that have been modified while the snapshot is active.

Comment: Let me be bold and obvious: **VSS is the only Windows API that provides the functionality that you want**. End of story. You're ignoring it at your own peril. You have already realized that other APIs don't let you do what you want to do. I hope the conclusion is clear.

Comment: It seems very odd that Windows doesn't allow me to open a file without locking at my own peril, as every other OS seems to allow this in some form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested in [Volume Shadow Copy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321273/VSS-API-IN-CPP).

Answer (score 1):

You certainly could copy the file and then check that the original and copy are identical (thus representing a consistent snapshot) prior to uploading to the server.

Comment: We are doing this; I didn't mention because the result is the same: during the copy, the file is locked.

Comment: How are you doing the copy?  When I download rather large XML files using IE (that take 10 minutes to complete), I can always make a copy using Windows Explorer to view a snapshot of the download-in-progress.  I'm pretty sure that my copy operation does not acquire any file lock.  IE already has a write lock as it's in the process of updating the file.

Comment: We're copying, encrypting, and (sometimes) zipping the file into a temporary file, which we then upload. We're doing it with plain winapi; `CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, and `WriteFile`. Most likely it's being opened with shared read. As a side note, these files are often multiple gigabytes.

Comment: Given the size of the files, I agree with @Juraj that Volume Shadow Copy may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363764.aspx), if using NTFS, you should be able to lock the file inside a transaction of yours, while uploading the file to a server. This will ensure your view of the file does not change, even if the file has been changed externally.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding transacted files, the file doing the write will not be using a transaction, so I don't think this will work.